# How to declare an export for all names

Tags: typescript

I want to create a definition for a file loaded by Webpack so that TypeScript will understand it properly. I am trying to do something like this:

```js
declare module "*.gql"
{
    import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";

    declare [key: string]: DocumentNode;
}
```

Such that any named import from a .gql file will have type `DocumentNode`.

```js
import { MyQuery } from "./query.gql";
// MyQuery should have type DocumentNode
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I donno if it is too late but this is how I do it:

```
declare module '*.gql' {
  import {DocumentNode} from 'graphql';

  const value: DocumentNode;
  export = value;
}
```

also found this:

```
declare module '*.gql' {
  import { DocumentNode } from 'graphql';

  const value: {
    [key: string]: DocumentNode;
  };
  export = value;
}
```

at [go here](https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag/issues/59#issuecomment-421887619)